# Replacing object ids in the complex data structure with newly created ones

Tags: python, mongodb, replace, objectid

I have a data structure that can be nested deeply as follows:

```
{
 'field1' : 'id1',
 'field2':{'f1':'id1', 'f2':'id2', 'f3':'id3'},
 'field3':['id1','id2', 'id3' ,' id4'],
 'field4':[{'f1': 'id3', 'f2': 'id4'}, ...]
 .....
}
```

and so on..The nesting can be at any depth and can be permutations and combinations of any data structures.

Here id1 ,id2, id3 are string equivalent of ObjectId generated using bson library and records are obtained by querying from mongoDB.
I want to replace all the occurances of these ids i.e; id1,id2... with newly created ones.

The replacement must be such that id1 must be replaced by a new id in all places by the same newly created id and same holds for the other ids.

To give clarity on the above:
if id5 is newly generated id, then id5 must occur in all places where id1 occurs and so forth.

Here was my solution to do the above:

```
import re
from bson import ObjectId
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime  


class MutableString(object):
'''
class that represents a mutable string
'''
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = list(data)
def __repr__(self):
    return "".join(self.data)
def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    self.data[index] = value
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if type(index) == slice:
        return "".join(self.data[index])
    return self.data[index]
def __delitem__(self, index):
    del self.data[index]
def __add__(self, other):
    self.data.extend(list(other))
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)


def get_object_id_position_mapping(string):
    '''
    obtains the mapping of start and end positions of object ids in the record from DB
    :param string: string representation of record from DB
    :return: mapping of start and end positions of object ids in record from DB (dict)
    '''
    object_id_pattern = r'[0-9a-f]{24}'
    mapping = defaultdict(list)
    for match in re.finditer(object_id_pattern, string):
        start = match.start()
        end = match.end()
        mapping[string[start:end]].append((start,end))
    return mapping


def replace_with_new_object_ids(mapping, string):
    '''
    replaces the old object ids in record with new ones
    :param mapping: mapping of start and end positions of object ids in record from DB (dict)
    :param string: string representation of record from DB
    :return:
    '''
    mutable_string = MutableString(string)
    for indexes in mapping.values():
        new_object_id = str(ObjectId())
        for index in indexes:
            start,end = index
            mutable_string[start:end] = new_object_id
    return eval(str(mutable_string))


def create_new(record):
    '''
    create a new record with replaced object ids
    :param record: record from DB
    :return: new record (dict)
    '''
    string = str(record)
    mapping = get_object_id_position_mapping(string)
    new_record = replace_with_new_object_ids(mapping, string)
    return new_record
```

**In short I converted a dictionary to a string and then replaced the ids and got the job done.**

But I feel this is definetly not the best way to do this as eval() can fail if i don't have suitable imports (datetime in this case) and also i may not have the info of type of objects (such as datetime etc.)in the DB beforehand.

I even tried the nested_lookup approach as described here https://github.com/russellballestrini/nested-lookup/blob/master/nested_lookup/nested_lookup.py

But couldn't quite get it to work the way i wanted.
Is there a better way to do this?

Note: **Efficiency isn't a concern for me**. All i want is to automate the process of replacement of these ids with new ones to save time manually doing so.

EDIT 1: I will be calling the create_new() with record obtained from MongoDB as its parameter

EDIT 2: The structure can have other objects such as datetime as values
      Eg:

```
 {
 'field1' : 'id1',
 'field2':{'f1':datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0), 'f2':'id2', 'f3':'id3'},
 'field3':['id1','id2', 'id3' ,' id4'],
 'field4':[{'f1': 'id3', 'f2': datetime.datetime(2017,11, 1, 0 , 0)}, ...]
 .....
}
```

The other objects must be untouched and only the ids must be replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to drill down to the strings that are nested in your input data structure.

```
def replace_ids(obj, new_ids=None):
  if new_ids is None:
    new_ids = {}
  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    return {key: replace_ids(value, new_ids) for key, value in obj.items()}
  if isinstance(obj, list):
    return [replace_ids(item, new_ids) for item in obj]
  if isinstance(obj, str):
    if obj not in new_ids:
      new_ids[obj] = generate_new_id()
    return new_ids[obj]
  return obj
```

`generate_new_id` is a function that should determine how you want to generate new ids.

Comment: What do u reckon is the best way to do this? using the recursive method or using the string replacement method?

Comment: The string replacement method is more vulnerable to you changing something that you don't want to, and less stable to changes in the structure of the id of your input data, so I would prefer the recursive method.

Comment: would the above answer hold if there exists key value pairs with values being other objects?Refer the EDIT 2 for more info

Comment: Well, the current function attempts to transform all strings. Any strings that are not ids you can simply leave the same (e.g. by changing generate_new_id() to transform_id(obj)), or by adding an additional filter. I would still favour this approach, as you are still very much restricted in what you are changing.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **michaelrccurtis** answer i could do the following:

```
from bson import ObjectId
import datetime


def replace_ids(obj, new_ids=None):
  if new_ids is None:
    new_ids = {}
  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    return {key: replace_ids(value, new_ids) for key, value in obj.items()}
  if isinstance(obj, list):
    return [replace_ids(item, new_ids) for item in obj]
  if isinstance(obj, str):
    if obj not in new_ids:
      new_ids[obj] = generate_new_id(obj)
    return new_ids[obj]
  if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
    return ObjectId()
  return obj


def generate_new_id(obj):
  if is_valid_objectid(obj):
      return str(ObjectId())
  return obj


def is_valid_objectid(objid):
  if not objid:
      return False
  obj = ObjectId()
  return obj.is_valid(objid)


a = {'_id':ObjectId('5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f845'),
     'a':'5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f844',
     'b':[{'a':'5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f844', 'b':'ABCDEFGH'},{'a':'5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f846', 'b':'abc123456789111111'}],
     'c':['5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f846','5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f844','5a37844dcf2391c87fb4f847'],
     'd':datetime.datetime(2017,11,1,0,0)
    }

b = replace_ids(a)
print(b)
```

Outputs:

```
{ '_id': ObjectId('5a380a08147e37122d1ee7de'), 
  'a': '5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e2', 
  'c': ['5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e0', '5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e2', 
       '5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e4'], 
  'b': [{'b': 'ABCDEFGH', 'a': '5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e2'}, {'b': 
        'abc123456789111111', 'a': '5a380a08147e37122d1ee7e0'}], 
  'd': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0)
}
```

Note : Answer may differ based on id generation on your machine.

Shout out to michaelrccurtis for an amazing answer